# c# http request session expired

Tags: c#, session, httpwebrequest

i am programming something that gathers several information from a website.
My probelem is that i always revieve from the webserver that my session is expired. Can you please help me to solve this problem ?

```
            CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.eurowings.com/skysales/Deeplink.aspx");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.CookieContainer = container;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string postData = "culture=de-DE&o=110&d=TXL&od=2016-11-23&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&lng=de-DE&t=o";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: does cookie-container has session data?

Answer (score 1):

So you are writing a web crawler.

I have noticed that you are not posting session id at all, so this is why it looks expired.

You should do two calls to this website:
 1. First call, which will start a new session and somehow will give you session id.
 2. Attach session id to your request, when you are looking for flights.

Comment: Hi Tadas, first of all thank you that you help me. Now I first made the request to recieve the coockiecontainer and than made another request with this container, but this made no change. Do you have an example ? Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example, I just noticed from your code that you are trying to attach an empty cookie container, which obviously has no session data at all. There is also a possibility, that you have to pass retrieved session id from the first call as a POST parameter. I would suggest you play around Fiddler or similar tool to see what exatly the website is doing behind the scenes, so you could replicate that. But I am 100% you will require two calls.